# Update records conditionally in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

The below is the data result I want to have (See the new column created).

| ID | Value | Type | New Column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | A | A_B |
| 234 | 1 | B | Null |
| 345 | 2 | B | Null |
| 456 | 2 | A | A_B |
| 567 | 3 | C | Null |
| 678 | 4 | C | Null |
| 789 | 3 | A | A_C |
| 890 | 4 | A | A_C |

Here I want to add a new column with Null, and update the value under this condition:

- If there is any value match between A and B, insert **A_B** in the new column where the type is A
- If there is any value match between A and C, insert **A_C** in the new column where the type is A

Currently, I completed to create the new column. My question is how to update the records with the above condition?

I will be happy to have any tips or advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We can produce the correct values by joining the table to itself, and SQL Server allows us to use these JOINs as part of an UPDATE statement.

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.[New_Column] = 'A_' + t2.Type
FROM [MyTable] t1
INNER JOIN [MyTable] t2 ON t2.Value = t1.Value AND t2.Type <> t1.Type
WHERE t1.Type= 'A'
```

See it work here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/xii7xujK

And thanks to @Stu for saving me having to build the fiddle from scratch.

Note that depending on your data and application, it may be possible for this to match the same `Type='A'` row more than once. In that situation, it's not fully deterministic which of the values will end up set for that row. If that matters, you should use an `APPLY` instead of a `JOIN`, so you can specify which of the additional rows "wins". Alternatively, there is also likely a `row_number()`-based solution that might be even faster.

---

I'll add that storing this data with the table seems like a mistake. Now we've shown there are multiple ways to query this information on demand based only on data previously present, storing this in a new column with the table (instead of, say, using a view or just running the query as needed) seems like it will also add maintenance burden and create a situation where it's possible for the new column to be out of date.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish using a correlation with *exists* and directly update the derived table of results:

```
update t 
  set t.new_column = nc
from (
  select *, 
    IsNull(
      case when exists (select * from t t2 where t.type = 'A' and t2.type = 'B' and t.value = t2.value) then 'A_B' end,
      case when exists (select * from t t2 where t.type = 'A' and t2.type = 'C' and t.value = t2.value) then 'A_C' end
    ) nc
  from t
)t
where nc is not null;
```

See [working fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/a3uEF0zq)

[image]